# importrange only allowing access for 460/462 of my sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

As the title suggests, I have individual sheets that carry data for each vehicle I work on.

Inside each sheet, it pulls make/model/vin/colour etc from a large inventory sheet where all the data exists.

I have made **470** individually numbered sheets all using the same importrange formula, and ***only #461 and #462 WON'T allow access*** to the sheet saying "Error linking spreadsheets. Make sure that you have access to the sheet that you're trying to import from." even though it has **worked for the last 460 sheets** and the next 8 sheets afterwards.

What gives? Below is the line that every single sheet has, that will not import data on only 2 of my sheets.

```
=VLOOKUP(B1, IMPORTRANGE("redacted", "List!B2:J"), 2, FALSE)
```

The sheet hasn't been updating in a month so there hasn't been any changes to the source of the importrange.

Comment: Are these two spreadsheets accessible to you? Are you the owner of the spreadsheets? You could try to refresh the formula by pressing the enter key twice with the cell selected. Sometimes it helps!

Comment: @GabrielPierce yes. I made all 470 and i'm an editor on the importrange data sheet. I've done the same thing 468 times and only 2 of them don't allow importing so its weird. I've even tried changing the data in the cell im looking for on those 2 and nothing works

Comment: Maybe try just importing a range and see what happens, don't run a VLOOKUP on it. Like A1-A10 for example

Comment: @GabrielPierce no luck unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

So your setup is you have 470 separate files that use the same sheet as reference via `IMPORTRANGE`. From this thread: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/65482894/importrange-doesn-t-work-because-there-are-too-many-files-linked?hl=en, there seems to be a limit of approx. 500 files that could get data from a single sheet, so you may be hitting this limit.

Note that it does vary from account to account, your case may have a limit of 468.

Copying from the thread, this seems to be the recommended solution:

> For reference, here is the  official response on this issue from June 2019 and then our interpretation of that below:

> Error "you cannot share with that many individual recipients" (or similar messaging)

> Error "make sure you have access to the sheet you're trying to import from".

> If you are seeing these or other access/sharing errors, you may have exceeded Drive's limit of unique "shared" entities on a document. Each IMPORTRANGE per source/destination workbook pair counts as one share. We don't anticipate any changes to this limit in the near future.

> For this case, the existing solution is to share the Sheet so that "Anyone with the link can edit" (rather than sharing with a list of individual users). Note: for GSuite domains, this would only work if you share publicly (beyond your domain), which is not recommended.

> Alternatively, intermediary sheets be used to break up the sharing count. 500 people import range from A, 500 more from B, both A and B get their data from C. Note: some sheets may already be far beyond this limit, so you may have to repurpose one of the existing sheets that already has access to the data as an intermediary.

Comment: He said that the cells after his initial 460 still worked "and the next 8 sheets afterwards."

Comment: That would still be just under 5000 cells (some of which, are empty). 462-470 don't have entries in the imported data so they are empty. BUT i've had a few empties so far, like 295 is empty data but it works. 462 and 463 are essentially the exact same imported data because their respective cells are empty, yet 462 doesn't allow access and 463 does.
Each numbered sheet is made from a template, I have not changed the template so I cannot for the life of me figure this out..

Comment: Empty cells are included in the import. Maybe you can also try option 2 as well.

Comment: Yeah either way, im importing 4500 cells. Empty or not. (9 columns, 500 rows). I don't see how #2 could work, considering after 461 and 462, I can pull more data just fine.

Comment: I guess you are importing 4500 cells per formula?

Comment: So my vlookup takes B1 (the car number), looks for it in the imported data sheet, and returns the year of the car in this case (col 2). The same formula is used again for the make/model (col 3) in another cell below that one. It makes it easier for my template rather than me entering the number each time I make a new individual car sheet.

Comment: I see. Since you used importrange twice per sheet at minimum, so 9000 cells are being imported per sheet. You may be reaching the maximum cell count of a Google Sheet https://support.google.com/drive/answer/37603 (5 million cells), that includes the actual cells in all your sheets.

Comment: Does this count every single sheet I have in my drive? Added up all the cells together, the max would be 5 mil?

Comment: So each individual sheet, calls 22,500 importrange cells then. I would only hit 5 million if I had half of my entries in a single sheet tabbed instead of individual sheets

Comment: Are all your sheets separate files?

Comment: Yes they are. 216 cells in each individual car sheet. 5 formula calls in each of them. So i'm importing only 22,500 cells in each sheet.

Comment: Edited answer. Looks like the number of sheets that are importing the same sheet that's causing the problem.

Comment: That seems like it could be the issue then. After deleting numbered sheets 461-470, and emptying the bin, I created a new #461 sheet and still get the same error. I did link 470-463 in descending order, then 462 and 461 couldnt link. So it should've fixed the error now but still nothing.